# The labels are not correct when I click the corresponding values

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def check():
    en.delete(0,END)
    letters = 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz'
    signs = '@#$%^&*!<>'
    digits = '1234567890'
    if pw.get() == random.choice(digits) + random.choice(letters) + random.choice(signs):
        strong = 'Very good password'
        strength.set(strong)
    elif pw.get() == random.choice(digits) + random.choice(letters):
        med = 'Medium password strength'
        strength.set(med)
    elif pw.get() == random.choice(digits):
        weak = 'Password too weak! Use another one'
        strength.set(weak)
    elif len(pw.get()) < 8:
        tooweak = 'Password not acceptable!'
        strength.set(tooweak)
    


win = Tk()
win.title('Password Generator')

lb = Label(win,text='Create a password')
lb.pack(pady=10)

pw = StringVar()
en = Entry(win,textvariable=pw)
en.pack(pady=10)

btn = Button(win,text='Create',command=check)
btn.pack(pady=10)

strength = StringVar()
lbstr = Label(win,textvariable=strength)
lbstr.pack(pady=10)
```

There is no error in this program. However when I run, and using the if statements inside `def check():`, the labels can't be shown if I use passwords satisfied with conditions in `strength.set(strong)`,`strength.set(med)` and `strength.set(weak)`. May I ask is it possible to use set method to change the text of label? Also may I ask is it correct that I put `random.choice(digits) + random.choice(letters) + random.choice(signs)` if I want a password to have digits,letters and signs within the entry? For this question, I already solved the problem by doing researches. If I encounter the same problem again, I will organize well my script and check the spellings and whether the methods used are correct. Before asking new ones, I will try my best first and ask only necessary.

Comment: None of your conditions make any sense, other than the length < 8 check.  `pw.get() == random.choice(digits)`, for example, is true if the password is a single character, matching a randomly-chosen digit - the test fails if the password is a different digit, or contains more than one digit.

Comment: Any method to use for containing different digits?

Comment: Can anyone help me please if someone know?

Comment: it make no sens to compare `pw.get()` with `random.choice(digits) + random.choice(letters) + random.choice(signs)` Maybe first see few times `print(random.choice(digits) + random.choice(letters) + random.choice(signs))` - everytime when you run it it generates random string with 3 chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you called `en.delete(0,END)` at the beginning of `check()` function and it leads to `pw.get()` return empty string.  It should be called at the end of `check()` function.

To check the weakness of the input password, you can create a list to hold the number of letters, signs and digits in the password.  Then you can use the list to determine the weakness of the password:

```
def check():
    letters = 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz'
    signs = '@#$%^&*!<>'
    digits = '1234567890'

    passwd = pw.get().strip()
    if len(passwd) < 8:
        tooweak = 'Password not acceptable!'
        strength.set(tooweak)
        lbstr.config(fg='red')
    else:        
        counts = [0, 0, 0]
        # go through each character in the password
        # and count the number of letters, signs and digits
        for c in passwd:
            if c in letters:
                counts[0] += 1
            elif c in signs:
                counts[1] += 1
            elif c in digits:
                counts[2] += 1
        print(counts)
        # check how many zeros are in the counts list
        zeros = counts.count(0)
        if zeros == 0:
            strong = 'Very good password'
            strength.set(strong)
            lbstr.config(fg='blue')
        elif zeros == 1:
            med = 'Medium password strength'
            strength.set(med)
            lbstr.config(fg='green')
        elif zeros == 2:
            weak = 'Password too weak! Use another one'
            strength.set(weak)
            lbstr.config(fg='red')
    # clear the password entry
    #en.delete(0,END)
    pw.set('')
```

Comment: May I ask if I want the label colour to be red where should I put ```fg='red'```?

Comment: Do you mean to change the label `lbstr` to red inside `check()` function or when `lbstr` is created?  If it is the former case, add `lbstr.config(fg='red')` inside `check()` function.  If it is the later case, just add it in `Label(...)`.

Comment: For ```zeros == 0``` I would like to set ```fg='blue'``` but for ```zeros == 2``` I would like to set ```fg='red'```

Comment: Just call `lbstr.config(fg=...)` in each if/elif block.